# Java. Выдаёт ошибку после запуска. Пропускает половину кода. Но запускает

Tags: java, type-error

Программа должна находить числа в интервале от 1 до N, которые делятся на сумму своих цифр. Когда запускаю код, выводит на экран массив и ошибку:

"Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero    at com.company.Main.main(Main.java:40)".

Что делать, кто знает? 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
package com.company;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        int N;
        int M = 0;
        int l = 0;
        int g;
        N = in.nextInt();
        N = N + 1;
        int[] mass = new int[N];

        for (int i = 1; i < N; i++) {
            mass[i] = i;
            System.out.println("mass[ " + mass[i] + " ]");
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++){
            g = mass[i];
            while (g != 0){
                M = M + g % 10;
            }
            if (g / M == 0){
                System.out.println("Числа делящиеся на сумму своих цифр: " + g);l++;
           }
        System.out.println("fdkvkldfnvlk" + M);
        }

        System.out.println("Кол-во чисел: " + l);

    }
}
//Я только начал изучать, не судите строго)
```

Comment: приложите информацию с изображений в виде текста, так будет работать поиск и проще будет решить ваш вопрос :)

Comment: у вас mass[0] получается равным 0, в итоге в нижнем цикле на первом проходе получается деление на ноль

Comment: Друзья, комментарии нужны для уточнения деталей, а не ответов.

Answer (score 1):

Не именуйте так переменные, а еще старайтесь писать код как можно короче и проще.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int maxValue = new Scanner(System.in).nextInt();
        int count=0;        
        for (int i = 1; i < maxValue; i++) {
            if (i%getSumDigits(i)==0) {
                System.out.println("Числа, делящиеся на сумму своих цифр: " + i);
                count++;
            }
        }        
        System.out.println("Кол-во чисел: " + count);
    }

    private static Integer getSumDigits(int number) {
        int result=0;
        while (number > 0) {
            result+=number % 10;
            number = number / 10;
        }
        return result;
    }

}
```

Можно немного функционалки :

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int maxValue = new Scanner(System.in).nextInt();
        int[] result = IntStream.range(1, maxValue)
                .filter(i->i%getSumDigits(i)==0)
                .toArray();
        System.out.println("Числа, делящиеся на сумму своих цифр: " + Arrays.toString(result));
        System.out.println("Кол-во чисел: " + result.length);        
    }

    private static Integer getSumDigits(int number) {
        int result=0;
        while (number > 0) {
            result+=number % 10;
            number = number / 10;
        }
        return result;
    }

}
```